# How to solve "invalid project" for webworks for blackberry 10

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10, blackberry-webworks

i have installed webworks for blackberry 10 in widows 8, but i am not able to open up projects from the web tool. i am always getting the "invalid project" error. Any one have an idea on how to solve this

Comment: Suggest also asking this in the BlackBerry WebWorks forums: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/bd-p/browser_dev.

Answer (score 1):

The format of your project must be compatible with the SDK.  If you created an old project using version 1.0 of the WebWorks SDK for BB10, then it is not compatible.  Version 2.0 introduced major changes to align with Cordova, which made changes to how project folders are structured.

You can fix this by first creating a default project using the new format, copying in your existing assets, and then open that project using the GUI:

1. Ensure the BlackBerry 10 WebWorks SDK 2.0 is correctly installed.
2. Open a command prompt (windows) or terminal (mac) and run the following command:

`webworks create <your source folder>\YourApp`

1. Replace the default YourApp\www folder with the \www folder from your existing project
2. Use the Web tool to open the YourApp project

Hope that helps.

Comment: See "How To Build" section of git projects like the below project https://github.com/blackberry/BB10-WebWorks-Samples/tree/WebWorks-2.0/BfB-Boilerplate-bbUI.js-0.9x